# c++ вопрос по итераторам

Tags: c++, итераторы

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема с имплементацией собственного контейнера похожего на std::map.

на данный момент у меня имеются iterator и const_iterator
мне нужно сделать их:

1. is_reference - тут насколько я понимаю просто нужно возвращать &iterator
2. is_convertible - тут самая большая проблема. Например, как сделать конвертирование дабы код ниже работал, я не представляю.

   ```
   using mapp = Map<int, int>;
   using mapp_it1 = mapp::const_iterator;
   using mapp_it2 = mapp::iterator;
   mapp_it1 tmp1;
   mapp_it2 tmp2;
   static_assert(std::is_convertible<mapp_it2, mapp_it1>::value, "iterator is not convertible to const iterator");
   tmp1 == (mapp_it1)tmp2; //Вот этот момент
   tmp1 != tmp2;
   ```

   очень сильно буду благодарен за подсказку, и возможный пример.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно определить либо конструктор mapp::const_iterator который принимает mapp::iterator, либо оператор приведения для mapp::iterator в mapp::const_iterator

Comment: а можно пример оператора приведения из mapp::iterator в mapp::const_iterator?

Comment: @Demolver оператор преобразования из типа `T` в тип `X` реализуется как функция-член в классе `T` в виде `operator X() const`. В теле функции нужно обеспечить возврат переменной типа `X`.